# Customize box size of code in Rmarkdown presentaion

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am making presentation using Rmarkdown and io2012 framework. I want to insert code in left side and plot on the right side. I tried by putting `out.extra='style="float:right"'` but plot is coming below the code. then I tried by writing code twice, once for plotting (`echo=FALSE`) and once for inserting the code (`eval=FALSE`). This time plot is getting overlapped with box (please see figure below). So I want to reduce the box size of code chunk. I have no idea how to do it. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Can't you get it to work if you encapsule the part to be two-column in  `<div class="columns-2">`  as described in the [ioslides presentation information](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html)